# Order of triggering functions in app.use

Tags: node.js, express

I've read that middleware functions are executed in the order they were added, so if I have the following:

```
app.use('/', function () {
    console.log('/');
    next();
});

app.use('/users', function () {
    console.log('/users');
    next();
});

app.use(function () {
    console.log('none');
    next();
});
```

In what order are they executed and why if the path is:

1. /
2. /users
3. /some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all of the endpoints:

1. `/`
2. `/users`
3. `/some`

only the first function will be called for the original code:

```
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('/');
});

app.use('/users', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('/users');
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('none');
});
```

That's because you didn't use `next()`. But if you had:

```
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('/');
    next();
});

app.use('/users', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('/users');
    next();
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('none');
    next();
});
```

Then:

1. For `/` - function for `/` and then `none`
2. For `/users` - function for `/`, `users` and `none`
3. For `/some` - function for `/` and `none` and a 404 handler

That's because:

1. `/` function matches all of the routes
2. `/users` function matches `/users` but not `/` or `/some`
3. no path means `/` by default so it matches everything

For details on path matching of `app.use` see:

- http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use

Comment: thanks, sorry, I certainly wanted to use `next()` in my examples, I'll update. Can you please add details to your answer?

Comment: thanks, _no path means / by default so it matches everything_ - does it apply to both `app.use(''`, and `app.use(function() {}` ?

Comment: @Maximus yes, it's the same if it's `app.use('/', function () {})`, `app.use('', function () {})` or just `app.use(function () {})`